# How can I get this menu bar in the center

Tags: html, css

I need some help, how can I place the navigation bar in the center? I tried using the text-align tag but that does not seem to be working!

as you can see the navigation bar is more close to the left margin and I want it to be in the center!

```css
#menubar {
  margin: -0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menubar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menubar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1px;
  float: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css" />

  <div id="page">

    <div id="menubar">
      <div id="menubar-container">

        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chi siamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cosa facciamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tree-Climbing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Galleria</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#menubar {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menubar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menubar ul {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

#menubar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1px;
  float: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css" />

  <div id="page">

    <div id="menubar">
      <div id="menubar-container">

        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chi siamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cosa facciamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tree-Climbing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Galleria</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: And now it seems bit close to the right side, it doesn't seem balanced in the center!

Comment: It is exactly in the center. I think you can check the distance from left and right.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS part :

```
#menubar {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin: -0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

#menubar a {
text-decoration: none;
color: darkgrey;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}

#menubar ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 1px;
float: left;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: large;
background-color: white;
}

body {
background: darkgrey;
}
```

The HTML5 Part:

```
 <div id="page">
 <div id="menubar">
 <div id="menubar-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chi siamo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cosa facciamo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tree-Climbing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galleria</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using 'display'

```
#menubar {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#menubar-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
#menubar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#menubar-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

#menubar {
  margin: -0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menubar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menubar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css" />

  <div id="page">

    <div id="menubar">
      <div id="menubar-container">

        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chi siamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cosa facciamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tree-Climbing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Galleria</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use float if you want to use text-align:center

see snippet it will work

```css
#menubar {
  margin: -0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menubar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menubar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css" />

  <div id="page">

    <div id="menubar">
      <div id="menubar-container">

        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chi siamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cosa facciamo</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tree-Climbing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Galleria</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fixed width to your menu and apply an auto margin to it.

`margin: 0 auto;`

Or you can use **[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** to do so.

```
#menubar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You will need some **[autoprefixing](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)** for the flexbox rules though.

Here is a **[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/v06rp4t5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y53se6e6/) fiddle helps

**CSS:**

```
#menubar { 
  margin: -0px; 
  padding:0px; 
  text-align:center; 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;  
} 

#menubar a {
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:darkgrey;   
  text-transform:uppercase; 
  display:block; 
  margin:0px; 
  padding:10px;
}

#menubar ul li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left:1px;
  float:left;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:large;
  background-color:white;
}

#menubar-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background: darkgrey; 
}
```